# JS ¿Como tomar los valores del Dropdown List para un triple select dinamico?

Tags: javascript, jquery

como puedo hacer que me tome cada uno de las opciones de los DDL, en el formulario hay 4 los cuales son (Pais->Region->Provincia->Comuna) pero al ejecutarlo solo me va tomando 1.

Me funciona y todo al seleccionar el pais y me rellene la región, pero de region a provincia no sucede nada y en peticiones me toma el de pais solamente.

```
<script>

    console.log('Ingreso');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#paises").change(function(){
          var categoria = $(this).val();
          $.get('/buscarRegion/'+categoria, function(data){
            //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
            console.log(data);

              var producto_select = '<option value="">Seleccione Región</option>'
                for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                  producto_select+='<option value="'+data[i].id +'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
                }

                $("#regiones").html(producto_select);

          });
        });

        $("#regiones").change(function(){
            var region = $(this).val();
            $.get('/buscarProvincia/'+region, function(data){
              //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
              console.log(data);

                var select_prov = '<option value="">Seleccione alex</option>'
                  for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                    select_prov+='<option value="'+data[i].id +'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
                  }

                  $("#provincias").html(select_prov);

            });
          });

        /*$('#provincias').change(function(){
            var provincia = $(this).val();
            $.get()
        });*/
      });

</script>
```

Aqui dejo el codigo en HTML de los SELECT, en caso de que haya un error mio o pueda complementarse con lo que poseo. Actualmente me encuentro trabajando con plantillas BLADE y Laravel.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>País</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboPais" id="paises">
                        <option>Seleccione un país</option>
                        @foreach ($paises as $pais)
                            <option value="{{ $pais->idPais }}">{{ $pais->nombrePais}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Región</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboRegion" id="regiones">
                        <option>Seleccione una region</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboProvincia" id="provincias">
                        <option>Seleccione una provincia</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Comuna</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboComuna" id="comunas">
                        <option>Seleccione una comuna</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: @alanfcm listo ahora si lo agregue, igual me di cuenta de unos errores que le faltaban los ID, pero sigue sin funcionar para provincia y comunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usando `on()` asi:

```
$('.form-group').on('change', '#provincias', function(){
        var provincia = $(this).val();
        $.get()
    });
```